# MySQL order by disregarding signed numbers

Tags: mysql

I have 10 rows with a column 'passion_level' that has both negative and positive values:

```
-3 5 8 9 -11 0 3 1 10 -8
```

If I run the query `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY passion_level DESC` I get the numbers ordered as you would expect, from high to low with the negative numbers at the bottom of the list. But how do we get mysql to order a column of signed integers disregarding the sign (treat negative numbers as positive numbers) so we get rows returned in this order:

```
-11 10 9 8 -8 5 -3 3 1 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
ORDER BY abs(passion_level) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ABS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs). It will return the absolute value:

```
mysql> SELECT ABS(2);
        -> 2
mysql> SELECT ABS(-32);
        -> 32
```

```
SELECT columnList FROM table ORDER BY ABS(passion_level) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try and create a new column and use ABS(), then reorder according to the new column desc

```
SELECT *,ABS(passion_level) as order FROM table ORDER BY ABS(passion_level) DESC
```